# Extracting lat/lon from PostGIS

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, osm2pgsql

There doesn't seem to be any column that represents lat-lon information for a particular node. I imported data into PostGIS using osm2pgsql. Any ideas on how to get this information?

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:** I got it working with this:

```
    SELECT ST_Y(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS lat, ST_X(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS long
FROM planet_osm_point;
```

Comment: I am trying to generate the long, lat information for given city column. there are 2 lakh records in my city table. Anyway with postgis?

Answer (score 1):

There are [many geometry output functions](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs) to convert a geometry to a human-readable form.

For example, using [ST_AsLatLonText](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsLatLonText.html) on a Point geometry:

```
SELECT (ST_AsLatLonText('POINT (-3.2342342 -2.32498)'));
      st_aslatlontext       
----------------------------
 2°19'29.928"S 3°14'3.243"W
```

Or if you need individual coordinates as floating point values, use [ST_X](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [ST_Y](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html) for longitude and latitude, respectively.

Comment: Thanks!

I used this to get it done:
SELECT ST_Y(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS lat, ST_X(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS long
FROM planet_osm_point;